# Multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Excel file which contains column for Oct month

- SLID - which represents User ID
- first_Meet_date
- Last_meet_date
- Total_meet_count
- cust_name
- Total_meet in Last90DAYS
- Active In 30Days

I have 4 tables

- SLUSR_USR with 2 columns SLUSR_USR_ID, SLUSR_USR_Cust_name
- SALES with 2 cols SK_STS_COMPANYID, SALES_DATE
- SK_COMPANY with 3 columns companyID, SK_COMPANYID, STS_SK_SLUSRID
- SLUSR_CLick with 3 columns SK_SLUSRID, STS_companyID, report_DATE

By using this query I'm getting total count of meeting by each ID

```
SELECT
    SLUSR_USR_ID, SLUSR_USR_CUST_NAME, SALES_COUNT 
FROM
    (SELECT
         SLUSR_USR_ID, SLUSR_USR_CUST_NAME, 
         COUNT(SALES_DATE) SALES_COUNT
     FROM
         SLUSR_USR, SALES, SK_COMPANY
     WHERE
         SLUSR_USR_ID = STS_SK_SLUSR_ID
         AND companyID = SK_STS_COMPANY_ID
         AND TRUNC(SALES_DATE) BETWEEN '01-Oct-2019' AND '31-Oct-2019'
     GROUP BY
         SLUSR_USR_ID, SLUSR_USR_CUST_NAME)
```

This is returning the Total_MEET_Count, SLID, and CUST_NAME

**Note**: No. of SALES DATE is equal to no. of meetings done by each SLUSR_user_ID and Report Date will give Active status for each SLID ->SLID is equivalent to SLUR_USR_ID -> companyID is assigned to each SLID -> one SALES_date means one meeting by each SLID )

Still I'm struggling with some of counts i.e and want to use below query in a subqueries

```
firsT_Meet_date
LAst_meet_date
Total_meet in Last90DAYS
Active In 30Days
```

For first and last meet date I'm using max and min function

```
SELECT 
    MAX(SALES_DATE), MIN(SALES_DATE), 
    SLUSR_USR_ID, COUNT(SALES_DATE)
FROM
    SLUSR_USR, DSR_SALES, SK_COMPANY
WHERE
    SLUSR_USR_ID = STS_SK_SLUSR_ID
    AND companyID = SK_STS_COMPANY_ID
    AND TRUNC(SALES_DATE) BETWEEN '01-Oct-2019' AND '31-Oct-2019'
GROUP BY 
    SLUSR_USR_ID
```

and also for Total_meet in Last90DAYS and Active In 30Days I want to use table SLUSR_CLick by using sysDATE-90

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server & Oracle again - was that intentional?

Comment: The question is a bit hard to follow, but I *think* you want to do selective counts, which can be done by expressions such as `sum(case when datediff(d,sales_date,getdate())<=30 then 1 else 0 end) as Last30days` (sql server syntax)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged